# Knockoutjs - make select display the current value of an observable as default value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BNXTm/1/

As you can see, even though the new consultant has the `Commercial` role, the select displays `Consultant` instead of `Commercial`. How can I make the select elements display the name of the consultant's role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value binding compare objects references to match selected value.

The Role object in the list and the selected object does not share the same reference

http://jsfiddle.net/BNXTm/4/

```
var c1 = new Consultant("Foo BAR", ko.utils.arrayFirst(contractViewModel.availableRoles, function(item) {
    return item.tag === "Co";
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create an computed which works with a plain value instead of objects:

```
self.role   = ko.observable(role);
self.role.forSelect = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        return self.role().tag;
    },
    write: function(newValue) {
        self.role(contractViewModel.getRole(newValue));
    }
});
```

This way `role` will always be one of the objects in `availableRoles`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/eCkL9/

Comment: dropdown still says consultant instead of commercial and text beside it now says consultant

Comment: Yes, it seems that when you use `role` instead of `role()` the binding works between the select and the text but doesn't care about what the consultant's role really is. I have not found yet how to make both work together, and it seems the be because I am using hashes instead of a basic array of strings.